# What is the terminology which refers to "non-cloud", "locally-installed", "not-internet-hosted" in the context of a category of software package?

Tags: terminology, administration

For example, if I wish to find a Google Docs clone which runs on a local server which I maintain, I should search for "Google Docs clone x", where x is the terminology I'm looking for.

Think Diaspora* software.

What is the terminology for this category of networked, but non-Internet-hosted, software solution? Does the terminology exist?

Answer (score 1):

- **On-premise** would be my first choice, especially if talking about hosting software on a server that is accessed internally.
- Client-side
- Local
- Pods (diaspora*)
- Node (depending)